# Completion using OpenAI and Php | Chatgpt

Tags: php, openai-api, chatgpt-api

Has anyone been able to get OpenAI's completion (dunno if is the correct btw) to work? I want to do the same thing as ChatGPT, even some variations of these 3 codes that ChatGPT has given me. When I ask ChatGPT to give me a summary and it gives me the answer, I ask it to tell me the parameters it uses.

It works well for me in the Playground, but when I try to use it in PHP, it doesn't work anymore. It basically returns the same text that I give it.

I've tried several configurations, tokens, temperatures, etc.

I've also searched this site and tried some things, although they're basically the same.

Also tried the TL;dr at the end.

The text length is 1900. Some text length are 500. The $tokens vary, from 60 to 200 with same result. I'm using Php

The text start with "summarise this: text here"

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions', [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$api_key
    ],
    'json' => [
        'prompt' => $texto,
        'temperature' => 0,
        'max_tokens' => $tokens,
        'model' => 'text-davinci-002', 
        'top_p' => 1,
        'frequency_penalty' => 0,
        'presence_penalty' => 0
    ]
]);

$json_response = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

// *******************

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$postFields = '{
        "model": "text-davinci-002",
        "prompt": "'.$texto.'",
        "temperature": 0,
        "max_tokens": $tokens,
        "top_p": 1,
        "frequency_penalty": 0,
        "presence_penalty": 0
    }';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $api_key;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) { echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch); }
curl_close($ch);


// *******************

$ch = curl_init();

$data = array(
    "model" => "text-davinci-002",
    "prompt" => $texto,
    "temperature" => 0.7,
    "max_tokens" => $tokens,
    "top_p" => 1,
    "frequency_penalty" => 0,
    "presence_penalty" => 0
);

$payload = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Authorization:Bearer ' . $api_key));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: "*When I ask ChatGPT [...]*" It's worth noting that ChatGPT is not a serious programming resource and shouldn't be relied upon as such. GPT models frequently (and confidently) provide suboptimal and outright incorrect answers to even routine programming questions, going so far as to "hallucinate" nonexistent libraries and language functionalities.